# If-else blocks not returning true on a condition that is clearly true, what do I do?

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, character-encoding, conditional-statements

I'm having some trouble understanding why the Scanner is not picking up the "(" character when it is clearly there. When I tried to save my program, there was a pop-up that said that some of the characters couldn't be saved in the proper encoding. (I'm using Eclipse, and it uses Cp1252 encoding if that would be of any help) I changed it to UTF-8, and now I'm having these issues.

```
String input = "a 0 ( b 4 ( * 100 b 6 ) w 9 ( x 3 y 5 ( * 2 z 3 ) ) )";
LinkedStack<TreeNode<String>> stack = new LinkedStack<TreeNode<String>>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String temp = in.next();
        System.out.println("Here's a temp:" + temp);
        if (temp == "(") {
            System.out.println("Continuing.");
            continue;
        }
        else if (temp == ")") {
            System.out.println("Closed Paren.");
            TreeNode<String> leftChild = stack.pop();
            TreeNode<String> rightChild = stack.pop();
            TreeNode<String> parent = stack.pop();
            parent.setLeft(leftChild);
            parent.setRight(rightChild);
            stack.push(parent);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Hit the else block.");
            String label = temp;
            String distanceString = in.next();
            double distance = Double.parseDouble(distanceString);
            System.out.println("Here is the distance of this node: " +distance);
            stack.push(new TreeNode<String>(label, null, null, distance));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `==` like that, the two string are checked to see if they have the same reference, which in this case will return `false`.

You should use `temp.equals("(")` and `temp.equals(")")` and so on.

Comparing the strings with `equals` method checks their values, which will be true here.

Comment: And that's the case because it is a String, which is technically an object, right?

Comment: Yes. But the address of the object will be different from the address of the string ")", despite their values being the same.